# Reverse CSS animation on :hover

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make an animation play reverse when hovering an element. It does not work, I don't understand why and how to get it to work. The "animation" just jumps back to keyframe 0% without any animation.

The snippet works only as intended in Chrome and Safari.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpBaZq

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: a;
  background-color: #a00;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: a;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes a {
  0% {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    padding: 100px 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This is just an extremely simplified example, so please don't suggest non-animation methods (except maybe an animation combined with a transition on `:hover` which I tried and couldn't get to work either).

This is much closer to the real-world code: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/eBxMqO

I am also not interested in Javascript-based solutions, only CSS.

Comment: Shrinking on hover is problematic because the element may become not hovered, and thus create a loop or behave in some weird ways. Don't do this.

Comment: As I said, it's just a simplified code example. This is much closer to my real use-case: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/eBxMqO My intention was to keep the code as simple as possible for the purpose of asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `reverse` I just created another animation which is the reverse of your current one.

I did it likes this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoeWLO

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: a;
  background-color: #a00;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: ra;
}

@keyframes a {
  0% {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    padding: 100px 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes ra{
    0% {
       padding: 100px 200px;
  }
  100% {
  padding: 50px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Correction**:
`reverse` is supported in Safari Desktop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

---

This is my guess on the jumping behaviour using 'reverse' - animation for keyframe `a` is not played again on hovering.

The animation of keyframe `a` is at 100% after 2 seconds. Now you move your mouse in. With the effect of `reverse`, `a` at 100% is now 0%, which makes it become smaller. But since keyframe `a` is already done playing, the div would just jump to 0% instead of transitioning to 100%.

Comment: Still has the jumps.

Comment: @Roberrrt Oh, that's because I am experimenting with that code pen. Will experiment on another instance. Try now, it should work.

Comment: Stack Snippit, try hovering in and out fast, it doesn't respect the current value. I'm not sure it's possible in CSS though.

Comment: @Roberrrt Well, that's because it only works on hover. If you move out during the animation, you force the hover animation to stop and the normal one to start, which explains the jumping.

Comment: Yeah, just thinking out loud here, would it be possible to freeze the current animation location and have it return to the original value on hover out?

Comment: `animation-play-state` supports pausing the animation. Not sure how that can be applied to an animation that goes both ways though.

Comment: +1 I got it to work this way, but still this feels completely wrong. I'd have expected `animation-direction: reverse` to achieve exactly that without duplicating alot of keyframes code. Ignoring Safari, any idea how to make it work with only one keyframe animation? This is much closer to my real use-case: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/eBxMqO

Comment: @connexo I couldn't find this in MDN documentation on keyframe, but it could be possible that keyframe `a` is not played again on hover, which would explain the jumping.