# How can I only use CSS to add an animation to change between "display:none;" and "display:block;"?

Tags: css

I add an animation when it become "display:block;" :

```css
.button:hover > .list {
  display: block;
}

.list {
  display: none;
  animation: listshow 0.8s ease normal;
}

@keyframes listshow {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div>Show</div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But how can I add an animation when it become "display:none;" ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse CSS animation on :hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225205/reverse-css-animation-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `keyframe`, you can set the element to `opacity:0` and then on your `:hover` set `opacity:1` and then add a `transition` to your your `list` class (since you are just playing with Opacity):

```css
.button:hover > .list {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div>Show</div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to change it between “display: none;” and “display: block;”, that may be unuseful. How can I realize it ? Thanks.

Comment: @HappyToKnow to my knowledge, you can't animate from `display: none` to `display:block` with just CSS as the element wouldn't exist in the DOM and you would have to reprint the element to the page and re-calculate the page size so the element can be added. You would need to use a mixture of javascript and css in order to add the element back to the page, reflow the element and then animate it